# Why does my program add ('', ' to the name of my file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code (sorry for the messy code):

```
def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
from easygui import *
import time
import os
import random
import sys

##multenterbox(msg='Fill in values for the fields.', title=' ', fields=(), values=())
msg = "Enter your personal information"
title = "Credit Card Application"
fieldNames = ["First name",'Last name','email',"Street Address","City","State","ZipCode",'phone','phone 2)']
fieldValues = []  # we start with blanks for the values
fieldValues = multenterbox(msg,title, fieldNames)
# make sure that none of the fields was left blank
def make(x):
    xys = x,".acc"
    xyzasd = str(xys)
    tf = open(xyzasd,'a+')
    tf.writelines(lifes)
    tf.writelines("\n")
    tf.writelines("credits = 0")
    tf.close
def add(x):
    nl = "\n"
    acc = ".acc"
    xy = x + acc
    exyz = xy
    xyz = exyz
    xxx = str(xyz)
    tf = open('accounts.dat',"a+")
    tf.writelines(nl)
    tf.writelines(xxx)
    tf.close

while 1:
    if fieldValues == None: break
    errmsg = ""
    for i in range(len(fieldNames)-1):
        if fieldValues[i].strip() == "":
            errmsg += ('"%s" is a required field.\n\n' % fieldNames[i])
    if errmsg == "":
        break # no problems found
    fieldValues = multenterbox(errmsg, title, fieldNames, fieldValues)
names = enterbox(msg= ('confirm FIRST name and the FIRST LETTER of the persons LAST name'))
##txt = "acc"
##na = str(name)
##name = (names)

life = ( str(fieldValues))
lifes = life,'\n'
herro = ("Reply was: %s" % str(fieldValues))
correct  = buttonbox(msg=(herro,'\n is that correct'),choices = ('yes','no','cancel'))


if correct == "yes":
    make(names)
    add(names)
elif correct == "no":
    os.system('openacc.py')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    sys.exit()
else:
    os.system('cellocakes-main.py')
    sys.exit()
os.system('cellocakes-main.py')
```

I don't know what the problem is also I am sorry about how sloppy it was programmed I have a white board to help me out still new to programming (I'm only 13) sorry. Personally I think the issue is in the def add area's syntax but because I am still new I don't see the issue personally I am hoping to have a more experienced programmer help me out.

Comment: Where does the program add what to what?

Comment: When you use `if __name__ == '__main__'`, you're supposed to put everything but the imports, class definitions, and function definitions in `main`. It's supposed to prevent your code from being treated as a script when it's imported as a module.

Comment: And please name your variables and functions properly, or otherwise when you are 30 and look into the code you wrote as 13-year-old, you will be very ashamed of yourself, trust me - been there :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of the question is here:

```
# assign the tuple (x, ".acc") to xys 
xys = x,".acc"

# now xyzasd is the tuple converted to a string, thus
# making the name of your file into '("content of x", ".acc")'
xyzasd = str(xys)

# and open file named thus
tf = open(xyzasd,'a+')
```

What you wanted to do is:

```
# use proper variable and function names!
def make_account(account):
    filename = account + '.acc'
    the_file = open(filename, 'a+')
    ....
```

On the other hand there are other problems with your code, for example the

```
def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

is utterly useless.

Comment: Thank you sir I am sorry for such a t rival question

Comment: thank you I started with python a few years ago but I've been struggling with some more "advanced things that was one of them I REALLY appreciate it

Comment: define "does not work" :D I changed names of some variables for you to understand your problem, but I did not write the whole function for you yet.

Comment: I know I changed it I forgot to get rid of my old code so it was redoing what the new stuff just did :/ can I ask you another question?

Comment: if you have another question then write another question

Comment: Yes Sir, SO when I create the NAME.acc file the 3rd line is credits = 0 during the check out process I want to boost that line (or create another) with the new number. e.g. 
1:[info]
2:
3:credits = 0
I want during the checkout process to update (or switch) to 1

Comment: I mean: open a new QUESTION.

Comment: Oh. but wont that make me a "help vampire" and thwy will close down my account

Comment: @user2649920 No, why? This site *is* for asking questions, kelping you become more experienced and if you are so, you might one day be able to help others, be it in a week, in a month or in a year.

Comment: ok My mother (also a programmer) got banned for being a help vampire after asking 2 questions

Comment: I asked the other questions :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer not directly answering your question.

Alas, comment fields are STILL not capable to hold formatted code, so I choose this way.

> ```
> def main():
>     pass
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     main()
> ```

This is a nice coding pattern, but used by you in a useless way.

It is supposed to prevent executing of the stuff if it is imported as a module and not executed as a script.

Nevertheless, it is not bad to use it always, but then put your code inside the `main()` function instead of adding it below.

```
fieldNames = ["First name",'Last name','email',"Street Address","City","State","ZipCode",'phone','phone 2)']
```

There is a `)` too much.

```
fieldValues = []  # we start with blanks for the values
fieldValues = multenterbox(msg,title, fieldNames)
```

The second line makes the first one useless, as you don't use `fieldValues` in-between.

It would be different if you expected `multenterbox()` to fail and would want `[]` as a default value.

```
def make(x):
    xys = x,".acc"
    xyzasd = str(xys)
    tf = open(xyzasd,'a+')
    tf.writelines(lifes)
    tf.writelines("\n")
    tf.writelines("credits = 0")
    tf.close
```

You was already told about this: `x, ".acc"` creates a tuple, not a string. To create a string, use `x + ".acc"`.

Besides, your `close` call is no call, because it is missing the `()`. This one just references the function and ignores the value.

A better way to write this would be (please name your variables appropriately)

```
    with open(xyzs, 'a+') as tf:
        tf.writelines(lifes)
        tf.writelines("\n")
        tf.writelines("credits = 0")
```

The with statement automatically closes the file, even if an error occurs.

Besides, you use `writelines()` wrong: it is [supposed to take a sequence of strings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines) and write each element to the file. As it doesn't add newlines in-between, the result looks the same,. but in your case, it writes each byte separately, making it a little bit more inefficient.

Additionally, you access the global variable `lifes` from within the function. You should only do such things if it is absolutely necessary.

```
def add(x):
```

Here the same remarks hold as above, plus

```
xy = x + acc
exyz = xy
xyz = exyz
xxx = str(xyz)
```

why that? Just use `xy`; the two assignments do nothing useful and the `str()` call is useless as well, as you already have a string.

```
for i in range(len(fieldNames)-1):
    if fieldValues[i].strip() == "":
        errmsg += ('"%s" is a required field.\n\n' % fieldNames[i])
```

Better:

```
for name, value in zip(fieldNames, fieldValues):
    if not value.strip(): # means: empty
        errmsg += '"%s" is a required field.\n\n' % name
```

Then:

```
life = ( str(fieldValues))
```

makes a string from a list.

```
lifes = life,'\n'
```

makes a tuple from these 2 strings.

```
os.system('openacc.py')

os.system('cellocakes-main.py')
```

Please don't use `os.system()`; it is deprecated. Better use [the `subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Thank your sir/mam I will take your advise but one thing.... I only know how to use `os.system` how do you use `subprocess`

Comment: @user2649920 There are [examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) for it in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html); I also added a link to the question.